# clientX, clientY javascript not working as expected in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a web page that displays a message when a user moves their mouse out of the page.  Everything works perfectly in all browsers except Internet Explorer.  In Internet Explorer, my code works, unless the user clicks on a form select item.  When the user chooses an item from the drop down list, clientX and clientY report an incorrect value, which makes my message display as if the user moved their mouse outside of the page.  The message should only display when the mouse actually goes outside of the page.  I am already using a work around for older versions of IE.  Does anyone know a different way of approaching this problem so that the code works correctly in older IE browsers (7-8)?

Here is my code:

```
if (document.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("mouseout", popMessage, false);
} else {  // IE before version 9
    document.attachEvent ('onmouseout', popMessage);
}

.
.
.
.

var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;

function popMessage (e) {
    mouseX = e.pageX;
    mouseY = e.pageY;

    if ('pageX' in e) { // all browsers except IE before version 9
        var mouseX = e.pageX - document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        var mouseY = e.pageY - document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
    else {  // IE before version 9
        mouseX = e.clientX + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        mouseY = e.clientY + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }

    if ((mouseY < 0 || mouseY > window.innerHeight-1)
    ||  (mouseX < 0 || mouseX > window.innerWidth-1))
    {
        abandonPanel.show();
        // alert("x:" + mouseX + "  y:" + mouseY + "  innerHeight:" + window.innerHeight + "  innerWidth:" + window.innerWidth);

        if (document.addEventListener) {
            window.removeEventListener("mouseout", popMessage, false);
        } else {  // IE before version 9
            document.detachEvent ('onmouseout', popMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check if you are in quirks or standard mode.

Answer (score 1):

Appended the code as follows

```
        else {  // IE before version 9
        if (e.srcElement.nodeName!="SELECT") { // IE reports inaccurate mouse information on SELECT elements
            mouseX = e.clientX + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
            mouseY = e.clientY + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        }
        else {
          mouseX = 50  
          mouseY = 50
        }

    }
```

This enters dummy values if the user has the mouse over a select element which keeps the javascript from misfiring.

Answer (score 0):

e.clientX only works like e.pageX when the target (srcElement) of the event is the document.

In tables and positioned elements as well as form elements the containing elements' offsets need to be taken into account-

```
var node=event.srcELement, mouseX=node.offsetLeft+event.clientX;
while(node.offsetParent){
  node=node.offsetParent;
  mouseX+=node.offsetLeft;
}
```

and also for the mouseY.

It would be simpler to ignore mousemoves until the srcElement is the body.

Comment: Message: 'offsetLeft' is null or not an object